# displaying images in reverse cronilogical order php

Tags: php, image

i have well over 1,000 pictures in a file all with random names, i need to display the latest 300 of them so that the one would of been the most recently added to the directory would be at the top. this is the kind of code i'm using so far:

```
foreach($images as $image) {
    echo '<a href="'.$image.'" traget="image""> <img src="'.$image.'"/></a><br /><br />';
}
```

(it also has it so that when i click on the image it gives me the raw ver.)

this seems to return all the imaged but in alpha/numerical order...

Someone please help been stuck for days. :(

$images is an array containing lots of stings that look like this: 'upload/[imagename].png'

Comment: You need to tell us where `$images` comes from and what kind of data it contains

Comment: You also need to change traget="image" to target="image"

Answer (score 0):

Sort `$images` by modification time:

```
function sort_by_mtime($file1, $file2) {
    $time1 = filemtime($file1);
    $time2 = filemtime($file2);
    return $time1 == $time2 ? 0 : ($time1 < $time2 ? 1 : -1);
}
usort($images, 'sort_by_mtime');
```